Help in modelling a cosmetic tube
I'm slightly new to Blender (using it after a long time and haven't been regular) and am currently working on modelling a cosmetic tube. I'm having a hard time aligning the bottle with the fringed end. Is there a way I can make these two cube objects be the same shape and get attached?

Now, this is the subjective part of the post and I'm not sure if this allowed here but I feel like the final result doesn't seem to resemble the product, although I have the general shape down. I feel like it could be an issue of the width of the tube, its very round at the top and very thin at the bottom - however, I'm unsure of how to correct this (if this is even the issue).
I used a reference image and, although nothing seems to be drastically wrong, it still doesn't look quite right. I'm also sharing the file temporarily in case it helps.


File:


Why are you connecting anything to anything at all? The tube is a single piece of plastic pressed at one end. It's not made of separate parts. I would start over. The trick is getting the form of the pressed part going to the round tube and the bumps at the end should be just an easy extrude operation.

@MartynasŽiemys I was actually kinda keen on starting over and making it one piece, but I wasn’t sure if I could add loop cuts just to the fringed end without messing up the rest of the tube.
If the loop cuts end up affecting the rest of the tube, would the extra geometry be an issue? I’m a bit nervous about getting more than I can handle.
